# I need tabular values from NDSolve for a parameter

Tags: differential-equations

I want a table to show the values of `p1` at different values of `x`, where `x` varies from `0` to `1` with increment `0.01`. Thank you in advance.

```
x = 0.9; a = 0.7; b = 0.5; d = 1; ϕ = Pi/3; F = 0; m = 1.0;
γ1 = 5; γ = 0.7; Sc = 0.6; Sr = 1;
Pr = 0.5; Du = 1; Br = 0.1; β = 0.2; Bh = 4; Bm = 2; Rex = 0.5;
α = Pi/3; Fr = 1; n = 1; Da = 0.5;
theta = 0;
h1 = 1 + a*Cos[2*n*Pi*x];
h2 = -d - b*Cos[(2*n*Pi*x) + ϕ];
eqs1 = ψ''''[y] - (1/γ1^2)*ψ''''''[y] - (m^2*Cos[theta]*Cos[theta] + 1/Da)*ψ''[y] == 0;
eqs2 = θ''[y] + β + Du*Pr*σ''[y] == 0;
eqs3 = σ''[y] + Sr*Sc*θ''[y] - Sc*γ*σ[y] == 0;
(*sol=NDSolve[{eqs1,eqs2,eqs3,ψ[h1]-F/2 == 0,ψ'[h1] + 1 == 0,
ψ'''[h1] == 0,ψ[h2]+F/2 == 0,ψ'[h2]+ 1 == 0,
ψ'''[h2] == 0,θ[h1] == 0,θ[h2]- 1 == 0,
σ[h1] == 0,σ[h2]-1 == 0},{ψ,θ,σ},{y,-1.5,1.6}];*)
sol = NDSolve[{eqs1, eqs2, 
    eqs3, ψ[h1] - F/2 == 0, ψ'[h1] + 1 == 
     0, ψ'''[h1] == 0, ψ[h2] + F/2 == 0, ψ'[h2] + 1 == 
     0, ψ'''[h2] == 0, θ'[h1] - θ[h1]*Bh == 
     0, θ'[h2] - (1 - θ[h2])*Bh == 
     0, σ'[h1] - σ[h1]*Bm == 
     0, σ'[h2] - (1 - σ[h2])*Bm == 
     0}, {ψ, θ, σ}, {y, -1.5, 1.5}];
p1 = Evaluate[{ψ'''[1.5] - (1/γ1^2)*ψ'''''[1.5] -
              (m^2*Cos[theta]*Cos[theta] + 1/Da)*(ψ'[1.5] + 1.0) +
              (Rex/Fr)*Sin[α]} /. sol]
```

Comment: Is there a more minimal problem that you can use as an example?

Comment: I'm trying to post a new question with minimal one.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this; it's fine.

```
h1 = (1 + a*Cos[2*n*Pi*Table[x, {x, 0, 1, 0.01}]]) // Flatten;
h2 = (-d - b*Cos[(2*n*Pi*Table[x, {x, 0, 1, 0.01}]) + ϕ]) //Flatten;

t1 = Table[ψ[h1[[i]]] == 0, {i, 1, 101}];
t2 = Table[ψ'[h1[[i]]] + 1 == 0, {i, 1, 101}];
t3 = Table[ψ'''[h1[[i]]] == 0, {i, 1, 101}];
t4 = Table[ψ[h2[[i]]] == 0, {i, 1, 101}];
t5 = Table[ψ'[h2[[i]]] + 1 == 0, {i, 1, 101}];
t6 = Table[ψ'''[h2[[i]]] == 0, {i, 1, 101}];
t7 = Table[θ'[h1[[i]]] - θ[h1[[i]]]*Bh == 0, {i, 1, 101}];
t8 = Table[θ'[h2[[i]]] - (1 - θ[h2[[i]]])*Bh == 0, {i, 1, 101}];
t9 = Table[σ'[h1[[i]]] - σ[h1[[i]]]*Bm == 0, {i, 1, 101}];
t10 = Table[σ'[h2[[i]]] - (1 - σ[h2[[i]]])*Bm == 0, {i, 1, 101}];

eqns = Join[t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, t6, t7, t8, t9, t10]
```

**I have Error down here somewhere, i recommend you try test every step you make to make sure it's all right!**

```
eqs1 = 
  Table[
    ψ''''[y[[i]]] - (1/γ1^2)*ψ''''''[y[[i]]] -
      (m^2*Cos[theta]*Cos[theta] + 1/Da)*ψ''[y[[i]]] == 0, 
    {i, 1, 101}];

eqs2 = Table[θ''[y[[i]]] + β + Du*Pr*σ''[y[[i]]] == 0, {i, 1, 101}]

eqs3 = Table[σ''[y[[i]]] + Sr*Sc*θ''[y[[i]]] - Sc*γ*σ[y[[i]]] == 0, {i, 1, 101}];

sol = NDSolve[{eqs1, eqs2, eqs3}, {eqns}, {ψ[y], θ[y], σ[y]}, {y, -1.5, 1.5}];
```

Comment: i used 101 length because in h1 and h2 give list of length 101

Comment: @Biswajit Mallick did you solved it !?